# Regular expression in xsd

Tags: regex, xsd

Could anyone please explain the following regular pattern means or what would be a valid value, I mean total how many character should be an so on.

```
    < xsd:simpleType name="GuidType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), commonly used in the "[uniqueidentifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)" type in SQL. It's a set of 5 groups of hexadecimal digits: a grouping of 8 digits, then a hyphen, then 4 digits, then a hyphen, then 4 digits again, then a hyphen, then 4 digits AGAIN, then a hyphen, then 12 digits. Hexadecimal digits are the numerals 0 through 9 and the letters A through F. Altogether (with hyphens included) this is a 36-digit string.

So for example, a valid string might look like this:

```
3B3AC4DC-3DEB-4241-99BD-5611A68C4CF3
```

Comment: I knew what it matched but didn't notice it is a GUID, nice catch +1.

Comment: @user2617417 - you're welcome! You can say more than thanks you know, you can accept my answer as the correct one! *nudge nudge*

Answer (score 0):

total regular expression

```
[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}
```

Breaks up in

```
[0-9A-F]{8} > explains : 8 chars that would be in set 0123456789ABCDEF
-           > explains: match character -
[0-9A-F]{4} > explains : 4 chars that would be in set 0123456789ABCDEF
-           > ..
[0-9A-F]{4} > ..
-           > ..
[0-9A-F]{4} > ..
-           > ..
[0-9A-F]{12} > explains : 12 chars that would be in set 0123456789ABCDEF
```